# Is there any option to Format date to desired format directly from JS controller in Lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC i am getting date filed from onclick event and tying to display that date in error message from JS controller. I want to change the format of the date in that error message.

HTML

```
<template for:each={schedule} for:item="sch" key={sch.Id}>
              <div key={sch.Id} class="reg-details">
                <div key={sch.Id}>
                  <div>
                    <span class="date-style">
                      <lightning-formatted-date-time value={sch.Scheduledate__c} key={sch.Id} year="2-digit"
                        month="short" day="2-digit" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" time-zone="UTC"
                        time-zone-name="short" hour12="false" weekday="long" class="date-text">
                      </lightning-formatted-date-time>
                    </span>
                    <!--reg-date-->

                    <button class="btn btn-terciary reg-btn" data-schid={sch.Id}
                      data-scheduledate={sch.Scheduledate__c} data-seminarname={sch.Seminars__r.Name}
                      onclick={bookSeminarEvent}>{label.register}</button>
```

from button tag i am getting scheduledate and storing in @track and using it in error message, it is not displaying in my desired format. How can i change that fromat from JS level.

JS Code

```
 else if(success === 'success'){          
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'successfully registerd for '+this.scheduledate,
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.ShowModal = false;
        }
```

Message i am printing scheduledate, NOw i want to change that format. like Aura is there any service called '$A.localizationService' to change date formats from JS controller level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an equivalent. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_i18n) for LWC's localization features.

Comment: const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(LANG); const date = new Date(this.scheduledate);
        dateTimeFormat.format(date); tried some thing like this but, this.schedule date in coming from html code captured in @track. Now dateTimeFormat is showing undefied. Please suggest some work around on this

Comment: You just have to make sure that the formatted date time is generated in a consistent way so the UI is updated when it is available - e.g. store it in a tracked property itself and ensure that it is generated in the setter for the this.scheduledate tracked property. Take a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_public for some tips on this sort of pattern.

Comment: If this doesn't help I recommend you post a completely new question with all the detail.